# PHP Looping through half the array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

So I have an array like this:

```
foreach($obj as $element){
//do something
}
```

But If the array contains more than 50 elements (it is usually 100) I only want to loop through the first 50 of them, and then break the loop.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The `foreach` loop will only loop thru the elements that exist in `$obj`. Do you mean only the first 50 no matter the size of `$obj`?

Comment: I guess he means looping through half of the array no matter what size it is. E.g. looping through the first 30 elements if the array contains 60 elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Works for **any** array, not only for those with numeric keys `0, 1, ...`:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($obj as $element) {
    // do something
    if (++$i == 50) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Clean way:

```
$arr50 = array_slice($obj, 0, 50);
foreach($arr50 as $element){
    // $element....
}
```

Normal way (this will work only for arrays with numeric indexes and with asc order):

```
for($i=0; $i<50 && $i<count($obj); $i++){
  $element = $obj[$i];
}
```

Or if you want to use `foreach` you will **have** to use a counter:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($obj as $element){
  if( $counter == 50) break;
  // my eyes!!! this looks bad!
  $counter++;
}
```

Comment: -1 (though I don't really have the heart to really down vote you) for offering a variety of solution.

Comment: LOL... don't worry. That's the idea of SO. Anyway... why the -1?

Comment: (I still didn't actually down vote) purely because of offering up the other two alternatives after array_slice which gets the job done fine given no limitations preventing its use were listed in the question.

Answer (score 11):

Loop through half.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($obj)/2; $i++)
{
  $element = $obj[$i];
  // do something
}
```

or if you want first 50 elements always

```
$c = min(count($obj), 50);
for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
{
  $element = $obj[$i];
  // do something
}
```

Comment: The first for won't work if the array contains, say, 60 elements.

Comment: Only works for arrays with integer keys that start with 0 and whose keys are consecutive.

Answer (score 4):

A neat alternative would be to make use of a couple of the [SPL](http://php.net/spl) [iterators](http://php.net/spl.iterators) like:

```
$limit = new LimitIterator(new ArrayIterator($obj), 0, 50);
foreach ($limit as $element) {
    // ...
}
```

The identical procedural approach has already been mentioned, see answers using [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice).

Comment: nice one... I feel like using Java `Iterator` interface!

Comment: this is the best awnser, for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0; $i < 50; $i++)
{
  // work on $obj[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 0, $el = reset($obj); $i < count($obj)/2; $i++, $el = next($obj)) {
    //$el contains the element
}
```

Comment: Ive never seen someone fit three functions in 1 loop iterator :/

Answer (score 1):

## Keep it simple

```
$filtered = array_slice($array,0,((count($array)/2) < 50 && count($array) > 50 ? 50 : count($array)));
//IF array/2 is les that 50- while the array is greater then 50 then split the array to 50 else use all the values of the array as there less then 50 so it will not devide
foreach($filtered as $key => $row)
{
  // I beliave in a thing called love.
}
```

Whats going on here

```
array_slice(
  $array, //Input the whole array
  0, //Start at the first index
  (
    count($array)/2 //and cut it down to half
  )
)
```

Comment: What if the array has 60 elements? It will count just the first 30.

Comment: Ok ive do a modification. heres the login

`IF (  (array / 2 is less than 50) then get a whole 50 else use all the array  )` its hard to explain it but should work.

Comment: OK... that will do work. But, why don't just use `array_slice($array, 0, 50)`?

Comment: i aint got a clue, i was just trying to give him the option of x/2, sooo i dunno, maybe I was wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most obvious approach to me:

```
$i = 0;          // Define iterator

while($obj[$i])  // Loop until there are no more
{
 trace($obj[$i]); // Do your action
 $i++;           // Increment iterator
}
```

Comment: this will end prematurely if any of the elements evaluates to false in the guard.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in all cases for half of an array regardless of length and whether it has numerical indexes or not:

```
$c = intval(count($array)/2);
reset($array);
foreach(range(1, $c) as $num){
    print key($array)." => ".current($array)."\n";
    next($array);
}
```